# Passing quoted string arguments to a bash script

Tags: string, bash, arguments

I have not been able to find a solution to this seemingly simple problem here or anywhere else. I want to get the paths of all files in a nested directory, add quotes around them, and loop through them in a bash script. Directory names and files can have white spaces in them. So far nothing I tried works properly. The quoted path strings always get broken up at the spaces.

`test.sh`

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

I tried reading from a file with one path per line, both single and double quotes:

```
find "nested directory with spaces" -type f | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' '\n' > list.txt # double quotes
./test.sh `cat list.txt`

find "nested directory with spaces" -type f | sed -e 's/^/'\''/g' -e 's/$/'\''/g' | tr '\n' ' ' > list.txt # single quotes
./test.sh `cat list.txt`
```

and command substitution with a space between quoted paths, single and double quotes:

```
./test.sh `find "nested directory with spaces" -type f | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/$/"/g' | tr '\n' ' '` # double quotes

./test.sh `find "nested directory with spaces" -type f | sed -e 's/^/'\''/g' -e 's/$/'\''/g' | tr '\n' ' '` # single quotes
```

Simply echoing a quoted path from the command line gives the desired result. What is missing in the script that can resolve the arguments into complete strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

```
find "nested directory with spaces" -type f -exec ./test.sh {} +
```

This will call `test.sh` with multiple arguments, without splitting the spaces in the filenames.

If your version of `find` doesn't support `+`, then you can use `\;` instead, but that will call `./test.sh` once for each argument.

For example, given the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo start
for i; do
    echo file: "$i"
done
```

The difference between `+` and `\;`:

```
$ find a\ b.txt date.txt -exec ./test.sh {} +
start
file: a b.txt
file: date.txt
$ find a\ b.txt date.txt -exec ./test.sh {} \;
start
file: a b.txt
start
file: date.txt
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. `find "nested directory with spaces" -type f -exec ./test.sh +` gives `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`. `find "nested directory with spaces" -type f -exec ./test.sh \;` or `find "nested directory with spaces" -type f -exec ./test.sh ";"` is slow with no output. Same result with my or your version of `test.sh`. Man page says `-exec utility [argument ...] ; … The expression must be terminated by a semicolon (``;'').  If you invoke find from a shell you may need to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat it as a control operator.`

Comment: I have had problems with the `-exec` primary. I am using `GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin12.5.0)` on OS X 10.8.5 and it is definitely not the standard `bash` so that may be part of the problem.

Comment: @hmj6jmh my bad! At the top of my post I forgot to write `{}` in there. I wrote it in the examples after that but it's easy to overlook. Btw, based on your error message it looks like your `find` does support the `+`, so it will work.

Comment: `find "nested directory with spaces" -type f -exec ./test.sh {} +` worked! Thank you!

One more question. This script lists non-existent paths like `nested directory with spaces/..files/*`. I think this is the result of previous failures when I tried to copy files to `nested directory with spaces/..files/`. I deleted the directory but it seems the shell still acknowledges it. How do I clear the shell?

Comment: @hmj6jmh I don't understand your question.

Comment: For reasons beyond my comprehension, I am getting output of non-existent paths like `nested directory with spaces/..files/*`. These are then passed to the script, causing errors. I thought maybe these are remnants still in the shell environment. I quit the terminal and restarted but they are still there. Is there any way to clear them?

Comment: @hmj6jmh there are too many to delete one by one? If you can formulate a `find SOMEFLAGS` command that outputs the files you want to delete, then you could delete them with `find SOMEFLAGS -delete`.

Comment: The files don't exist. They are not listed by `ls -aR`.

Comment: I checked again and there was a subdirectory named `..files` with a huge number of subdirectories under that so I deleted them and all works fine.