# How can I pass a quoted string as a single argument via bash variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have an application where I receive a part of command line argument via bash exports.

```
[env.sh] 
export options="-def \"hello world\""

[run.sh]
source ./env.sh 
myprogram $options
```

When I execute run.sh, I would expect that myprogram will receive arguments in following list

```
argv[0] myprogram
argv[1] -def
argv[2] hello world
```

However, what really happens is ...

```
argv[0] myprogram
argv[1] -def
argv[2] "hello
argv[3] world"
```

So the quoting around "hello world" becomes part of 2 separate command line argument.

How can I pass a command line option that includes quoted string via bash variable? I am using bash, but I can use other shells if necessary..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing quoted string arguments to a bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307196/passing-quoted-string-arguments-to-a-bash-script)

Comment: [Don't use a string. Use an array.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array will take care of all the quoting issues.

```
[env.sh] 
options=(-def "hello world")

[run.sh]
source ./env.sh 
myprogram "${options[@]}"
```

`export` keyword removed since it is unnecessary here and also doesn't work for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without changing `env.sh`:

```
IFS=$'"'
opt=($options)
myprogram "${opt[@]}"
```